# Install Python 3.7 packages in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, python, 20.04, virtualenv

I recently upgraded to 20.04 from 19.10. Now i face issues since i need to use a virtual environment with Python 3.7 and cant seem to install the packages:
- Python3.7-venv
- Python 3.7-dev

Seems like these are not supported by 20.04.

Any way to install them for 20.04? 
Would they still have worked if i didnt do autoremove during the upgrade?

I hope to avoid having to reinstall 19.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu 20.04, you will get bydefault Python 3.8 version.  If you want to install Python 3.7, you can download [python 3.7 tarball file](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.7/Python-3.7.7.tgz) and install it.

```
tar -xvzf Python-3.7.7.tgz
pip install .
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Python 3.7 installs just fine. The problem is that i cant seem to install the packages i need on 20.04. Is there a way to install the 19.10 package, and make it run on 20.04? https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3.7-venv+&searchon=names

Comment: You can manually download and try to install debian packages by sudo dpkg -i  from eon ubuntu packages. 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/python3.7-venv
https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/python3.7-dev 
You can install depedencies if required by downloading packages. This can be workaround but not preferred way.

Comment: Thank you, ill keep that in mind for later. I got my script working now by using python3.8 venv and replacing dependencies towards 3.7.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than building from source or using packages from different Ubuntu versions I would recommend using the [Deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). This provides both newer and older versions of Python than are in the Ubuntu archive, and keeps those versions up to date with bugfix releases.