# How do you install python3.7 to ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, python3

I'm an inexperienced Linux user but have been fiddling around for a few months. I need to use python 3.5-3.7 for a project, but cannot install python3.7 from a tarball like mentioned here: [Install Python 3.7 packages in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235532/install-python-3-7-packages-in-ubuntu-20-04)

I've provided the output to the terminal here:(sorry it's so long i don't know what's relevant)

[See error log](https://pastebin.com/96T9GcWc)

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-_od32i_x/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-_od32i_x/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-spo6ltjl
       cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-_od32i_x/
  Complete output (230 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers
 building '_ctypes_test' extension
 creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_ctypes
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _ctypes/_ctypes_test.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_ctypes/_ctypes_test.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _ctypes/_ctypes_test.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_contextvars' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _contextvarsmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_contextvarsmodule.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _contextvarsmodule.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_json' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _json.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_json.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _json.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_testcapi' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _testcapimodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_testcapimodule.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _testcapimodule.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_testbuffer' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _testbuffer.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_testbuffer.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _testbuffer.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_testimportmultiple' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _testimportmultiple.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_testimportmultiple.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _testimportmultiple.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_testmultiphase' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _testmultiphase.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_testmultiphase.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _testmultiphase.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_lsprof' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _lsprof.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_lsprof.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _lsprof.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_opcode' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _opcode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_opcode.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _opcode.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_asyncio' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _asynciomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_asynciomodule.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _asynciomodule.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_queue' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _queuemodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_queuemodule.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _queuemodule.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building 'parser' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c parsermodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/parsermodule.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: parsermodule.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building 'mmap' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c mmapmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmapmodule.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: mmapmodule.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_xxtestfuzz' extension
 creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_xxtestfuzz
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _xxtestfuzz/_xxtestfuzz.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_xxtestfuzz/_xxtestfuzz.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _xxtestfuzz/_xxtestfuzz.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building 'audioop' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c audioop.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/audioop.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: audioop.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_crypt' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _cryptmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_cryptmodule.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _cryptmodule.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_ssl' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _ssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_ssl.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _ssl.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_hashlib' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _hashopenssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_hashopenssl.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _hashopenssl.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building 'termios' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c termios.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/termios.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: termios.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building 'resource' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c resource.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/resource.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: resource.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building 'nis' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c nismodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/nismodule.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: nismodule.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_curses' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DHAVE_NCURSESW=1 -I/usr/include/ncursesw -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _cursesmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_cursesmodule.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _cursesmodule.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_curses_panel' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DHAVE_NCURSESW=1 -I/usr/include/ncursesw -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _curses_panel.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_curses_panel.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _curses_panel.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_multibytecodec' extension
 creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cjkcodecs
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c cjkcodecs/multibytecodec.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cjkcodecs/multibytecodec.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: cjkcodecs/multibytecodec.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_codecs_kr' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_kr.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cjkcodecs/_codecs_kr.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_kr.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_codecs_jp' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_jp.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cjkcodecs/_codecs_jp.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_jp.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_codecs_cn' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_cn.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cjkcodecs/_codecs_cn.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_cn.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_codecs_tw' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_tw.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cjkcodecs/_codecs_tw.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_tw.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_codecs_hk' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_hk.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cjkcodecs/_codecs_hk.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_hk.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_codecs_iso2022' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_iso2022.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cjkcodecs/_codecs_iso2022.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_iso2022.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_decimal' extension
 creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_decimal
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DCONFIG_64=1 -DASM=1 -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _decimal/_decimal.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_decimal/_decimal.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _decimal/_decimal.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_multiprocessing' extension
 creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_multiprocessing
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -IModules/_multiprocessing -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _multiprocessing/multiprocessing.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_multiprocessing/multiprocessing.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _multiprocessing/multiprocessing.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building 'ossaudiodev' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ossaudiodev.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ossaudiodev.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: ossaudiodev.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building 'xxlimited' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPy_LIMITED_API=0x03050000 -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c xxlimited.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/xxlimited.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: xxlimited.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 building '_ctypes' extension
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I. -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c _ctypes/_ctypes.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_ctypes/_ctypes.o
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: _ctypes/_ctypes.c: No such file or directory
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
 
 Python build finished successfully!
 The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
 _bz2                  _dbm                  _elementtree
 _gdbm                 _lzma                 _sqlite3
 _tkinter              _uuid                 readline
 spwd
 To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
 
 
  The following modules found by detect_modules() in setup.py, have been
  built by the Makefile instead, as configured by the Setup files:
  _abc                  _bisect               _blake2
  _csv                  _datetime             _heapq
  _md5                  _pickle               _posixsubprocess
  _random               _sha1                 _sha256
  _sha3                 _sha512               _socket
  _struct               array                 atexit
  binascii              cmath                 fcntl
  grp                   math                  pwd
  pyexpat               select                syslog
  time                  unicodedata           zlib
 
 
  Failed to build these modules:
  _asyncio              _codecs_cn            _codecs_hk
  _codecs_iso2022       _codecs_jp            _codecs_kr
  _codecs_tw            _contextvars          _crypt
  _ctypes               _ctypes_test          _curses
  _curses_panel         _decimal              _hashlib
  _json                 _lsprof               _multibytecodec
  _multiprocessing      _opcode               _queue
  _ssl                  _testbuffer           _testcapi
  _testimportmultiple   _testmultiphase       _xxtestfuzz
  audioop               mmap                  nis
  ossaudiodev           parser                resource
  termios               xxlimited
 
 
  Could not build the ssl module!
  Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
  LibreSSL 2.6.4 and earlier do not provide the necessary APIs, https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/381
 
  running build_scripts
  creating build/scripts-3.8
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/Tools/scripts/pydoc3'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Python
  Running setup.py clean for Python
Failed to build Python
Installing collected packages: Python
    Running setup.py install for Python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-_od32i_x/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-_od32i_x/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-kzs09dnd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/beany_lass/.local/include/python3.8/Python
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-_od32i_x/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help
   
    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-_od32i_x/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-_od32i_x/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-kzs09dnd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/beany_lass/.local/include/python3.8/Python Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just create a virtual environment for each version of python?
I dont use Ubuntu 20.04, only 1804 but that was what I did.

Comment: [Building Python 3.7.1 - SSL module failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53543477/) solves the error message, but so does installing Python 3.7 from ppa:deadsnakes/ppa.

Comment: i switched to using conda some time back.  so far i haven't encountered any difficulties. https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For newer Python I prefer the [deadsnake ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).
For installing it, try this:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.7
```

```
$ python3.7 -V
Python 3.7.7
```

Comment: I get a "Package 'python3.7' has no installation candidate" with this.

Answer (score 4):

The Python 3.7 package from the official Ubuntu 19.10 repositories can be installed in Ubuntu 20.04 without adding any new repositories to your software sources by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update  
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi6_3.2.1-9_amd64.deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.7/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.5-2~19.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.7/libpython3.7-minimal_3.7.5-2~19.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.7/python3.7-minimal_3.7.5-2~19.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.7/python3.7_3.7.5-2~19.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libffi6_3.2.1-9_amd64.deb ./libpython3.7-minimal_3.7.5-2~19.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.5-2~19.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python3.7-minimal_3.7.5-2~19.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python3.7_3.7.5-2~19.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Add Python 3.7 to update-alternatives so that you can switch between Python 3.8 and Python 3.7 by running `update-alternatives --config python3`.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7
update-alternatives --config python3
```

Comment: I would not prefer this method because the corresponding package is not supplied with security updates. Also, Ubuntu 19.4 is EOL.

Comment: @moep My answer is the preferred solution from the overriding *security* standpoint because I have only used packages from official Ubuntu sources and you have added a PPA which is not vetted by Canonical to your software sources. You seem to think that PPAs are the more virtuous solution because the software in the PPA is updated, but security is the more important factor. The truth is that you should avoid adding a PPA to your software sources if possible. [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/)